# Bash string, passed to GDB

Tags: bash, sh

I'm trying to write a bash script to autorestart a application i have.
But sometimes i want to have the program run in GDB. Anyways this is not where the issue is.

If you watch this gist:
https://gist.github.com/Lillecarl/5421446

You will see that on line 91 i "call" the file gdbcommands. It really really really grinds my gears that i must have this a external file, do anyone of you gurus have any suggestions on how to merge this into wowadmin.sh? In case it must, it can be a separate file. But i would prefer it to be completely inside the sh file.

Answer (score 3):

You can pass multiple command using -ex switch. For some reason it is not documented in man (at least on my CentOS), but appears in full gdb manual http://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb.html#Invocation

```
 gdb -ex 'print "one"' -ex 'print "two"' my_prog
```